# CSS3 Nth Child ordering

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking to target elements using nth-child, there are 3 colours (grey-1, grey-2 and grey-3).

On the fourth element, I want the colours to loop e.g.

- Grey-1
- Grey-2
- Grey-3
- Grey-1
- Grey-2
- Grey-3

What is the most efficient way of doing this, I have the option of using jQuery but would prefer using CSS3. The list maybe long, which is why I don't want to change the dom with .addClass().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**MDN - `nth-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
>
> The `:nth-child(an+b)` CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has `an+b-1` siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for `n`, and has a parent element. More simply stated, the selector matches a number of child elements whose numeric position in the series of children matches the pattern `an+b`.

In order to select every third element, you would use `:nth-child(3n)`. Increment `b` accordingly in order to target all the elements `:nth-child(3n+1)`, `:nth-child(3n+2)`, `:nth-child(3n+3)`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/98nqww5x/)

```
div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: #ccc;
}
div:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: #ddd;
}
div:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```css
div {
    height: 20px;
}
div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: #ccc;
}
div:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: #ddd;
}
div:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the elements are the direct children of a common container (*for example `li` children of a `ul`*), you can do

```css
li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  color: green
}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  color: blue
}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```